# python 2.6 create volatile registry entry

Tags: python, registry

I am trying to create a volatile registry entry.

Initially I had tried to create something like this but it failed

**First Approach**

```
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, volatilePath)
Registrykey= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, volatilePath, 0, KEY_WRITE)
SetValueEx(Registrykey,"pid", 0, REG_SZ, "1234")
CloseKey(Registrykey)
```

**Second approach**

```
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
key = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, volatilePath)
Registrykey= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, volatilePath, 0, KEY_WRITE)
SetValueEx(Registrykey, "pid", 0, REG_SZ|REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, "1234")
CloseKey(Registrykey)
```

Finally seeing that the key is not working as volatile (working as a normal key), I want to call the Windows native function that is [specified here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx). I am new to Python. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**An Update: Latest approach (Still not working)**

```
from ctypes import windll
from _winreg import *  
import win32api
p=PySECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(None, None)
advapi32 = windll.LoadLibrary ( 'advapi32.dll' )
win32api.RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, u"Volatile Environment", 0, None, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, p )
Registrykey= OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, volatilePath, 0, KEY_WRITE)
SetValueEx(Registrykey, "pid", 0, REG_SZ, "1234")
```

Here I am getting an error,

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: If you're familiar with C programming and want a standard-library solution, use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ctypes.html). If adding a large dependency to your project is ok, choose PyWin32's [`win32api.RegCreateKeyEx`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32api__RegCreateKeyEx_meth.html).

Comment: BTW, are you planning to access a remote registry? If not, calling `ConnectRegistry` does nothing, and you're not using the `aReg` handle anyway.

Comment: @eryksun PyWin32 might not be an option. ctypes looks ok. In either/both cases, can you point to a link that I can refer to create a sample or if you can help me with some code? Your direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Basically I am stuck at trying to create an object of PySECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

Comment: If you're using win32api, then you don't need _winreg or ctypes. FYI, the win32api parameters have default values. Also, you don't need `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` for the HKCU hive; that's just for HKLM.

Comment: `import win32api, win32con, winnt;` `hKey, flag = win32api.RegCreateKeyEx(win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Volatile Environment', win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS, Options=winnt.REG_OPTION_VOLATILE);` `win32api.RegSetValueEx(hKey, 'pid', 0, winnt.REG_SZ, '1234')`.

Comment: You are my hero @eryksun. Please post this as an answer so that I can upvote and accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a standard-library solution, use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/ctypes.html). However, if adding an external dependency to your project is acceptable, I recommend to instead use PyWin32's [`win32api.RegCreateKeyEx`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32api__RegCreateKeyEx_meth.html), especially if you're not experienced in C. For pip installation, PyWin32 is available on PyPI as [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32), but it's not availble there for Python 2.6. If possible you should upgrade to the latest version of Python 2.7.

PyWin32 example:

```
import winnt
import win32api
import win32con

hKey, flag = win32api.RegCreateKeyEx(
                    win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                    'Volatile Environment', 
                    win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 
                    Options=winnt.REG_OPTION_VOLATILE)

win32api.RegSetValueEx(hKey, 'pid', 0, winnt.REG_SZ, '1234')
```

FYI, you don't need `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` access for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive. WOW64 redirection only affects keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.